# Проверить нажатие Shift

Tags: c#, wpf

Как проверить нажатие клавиши Shift в обработчике события прокрутки колёсика? У меня он вот такой:

```
 private void cnv_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var isShiftPressed = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0;
```